# templates copy constructor errors

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Here is a minimal code that shows the problem:

```
template<typename To, typename From> To convert(const From& x);

struct A
{
    int value;
    template<typename T> A(const T& x) { value = convert<A>(x).value; }
};

struct B : public A { };

int main()
{
    B b;
    A a = b;
}
```

It gives me: `undefined reference to 'A convert<A, B>(B const&)'`

As expected, as I removed the default copy constructor. But if I add this line to `A`:

```
A(const A& x) { value = x.value; }
```

I get the same error. If I try to do this way: (adding a template specialization)

```
template<> A(const A& x) { value = x.value; }
```

I get: `error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct A'`.

How to solve it?

My compiler is MinGW (GCC) 4.6.1

EDIT:

The `convert` functions converts from many types to `A` and back again. The problem is that don't make sense writing a convert function from `B` to `A` because of the inheritance. If I remove the line that calls `convert` from `A` it just works. The idea is to call `convert` for all times that do't inherit from `A`, for these, the default constructor should be enough.

Comment: What's the problem? Your `convert` function has no definition, so you get a linker error. Say `A a(static_cast<A&>(b));` if you deliberately want to trigger slicing.

Comment: The last error can be fixed by moving the specialisation outside the class definition; it won't help though, since the `A a = b;` requires a specialisation for `B`, not `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for as I understand, when `b` is passed, as `b` is not an object of `A`, copy constructor is not called, instead the template constructor is called.

However, if an object of the derived class is passed, you want the copy constructor of `A` to be called.

For this, there is one solution using `<type_traits>` (c++0x):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename To, typename From> To convert(const From& x);

struct A
{
    int value;
    template<typename T> A(const T& x, 
        const typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<A,T>::value, bool>::type = false) 
    { value = convert<A>(x).value; }
    A(){}
};

struct B : public A { };

int main()
{
    B b;
    A a = b;
}
```

The template is disabled why an object of a class derived from `A` is passed, so the only available constructor is the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "undefined reference" should be easily solved by linking in the implementation of the function!

NOTE: as things stand, returning a copy will trigger a stack overflow.

EDIT: IMO, your design is flawed, you have moved the construction logic outside of `A` into `convert`; rather than this, you should provide specific conversion constructors in `A`. It's either that or some `boost::enable_if` trick to disable the conversion constructor if the passed in type is derived from `A` (you can use one of the `type_traits` for that). For example, if you can construct an `A` from an `int`, provide the specific constructor in `A` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by defining the convert function :

```
template<typename To, typename From> const To& convert(const From& x)
{
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> As expected, as I removed the default copy constructor.

No; while you do need to replace the default copy constructor, its omission causes a different sort of problem (and only if you have the sort of calling code that needs it).

The error you report:

```
undefined reference to 'A convert<A, B>(B const&)
```

is a linker error. It is telling you that you don't actually have a `convert` function anywhere.

```
error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct A'
```

You were right the first time about how to put back the default copy constructor. However, that's still irrelevant to the linker error.

Comment: Why do you need to replace the default copy constructor? It's still there, and will be chosen instead of the template if the source object has type `A`.

Comment: You quite sure it's still there? That doesn't match my experience at all.

Comment: [Yes](http://ideone.com/axKpn). According to C++11, 12.8/8, "If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, there is no user-declared move constructor,
and there is no user-declared move assignment operator, a copy constructor is implicitly declared as
defaulted."